# Flutter- Not detecting a connected device

Tags: flutter

So I've set up flutter on visual studio code and I am trying to run my app on a connected device but it just wont detect the android device. When I run flutter doctor it also doesn't detect it, I have enabled USB debugging and activated developer mode on my device but it still will not work. I have tried another device to no affect, I've pretty much tried everything and I appear to have come to a standstill with no hope. Any help and advice is much appreciated. The device I am using is Pixel 2 XL

Comment: What OS on your computer do you using? Your computer detecting your device?

Comment: I am using windows 10 64 bit OS and yes it detects the device and shows up devices and drives when I set the USB preferences to file transfer or to PTP

Comment: Try to revoke and enable again "Developer Mode" and USB debugging and set USB configuration to "File Transfer" (or similar).

Comment: Have you installed Android Debugging Bridge (ADB) for Pixel 2? Visit this link to download and install ADB https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

Comment: I've tried revoking and enabling developer mode to no success. I'll download the link and let you know if I make any progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `adb devices` command in your terminal, check if output it's something like:

[image]

If I don’t show that the problem is the adb

Comment: Everytime I run that command it says adb is not recognised

Comment: platform-tools is declared in you PATH of environment?

Comment: If adb is not properly installed, then Flutter won't be able to find your devices.

Comment: How would I go about properly installing it ? Sorry for the amount of questions, I'm quite new to flutter

Comment: The way to add in your PATH is different for each operating system

Comment: "To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager." I get this error when trying to run it on my phone??

Comment: run flutter doctor command and see if everything is ok